# Batch script not working as expected

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to find drive letters and create one tmp.txt file in each drive 
if i able to create file it should print file created else not. Below what i did but didnt work as expected.

```
del volumes.txt
del test.log
mountvol | findstr :\ >> volumes.txt
for /F "delims= " %%b in (volumes.txt) do (
  for /f  "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (`fsutil file createnew %%btmp.txt 1 2^>^&1`) do (
    for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%# in ("%%a") do set "result=%%~#" (
      if %result% equ "created" (
        echo File creted >> test.log
      ) else (
        echo Failed to create >> test.log
      )
    )
  )
)
```

it shows Failed to create for all drives in test.log even if tmp.txt created in drives

Comment: Instead, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21410817/886887).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%# in ("%%a") do set "result=%%~#" (
  if %result% equ "created" (
```

to

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%# in ("%%a") do (
  if "%%~#" equ "created" (
```

There is no apparent reason for assigning the value to `result` and even then, you'd need to invoke `delayedexpansion` and use `!result!` instead of `%result%` (see endless So items about `delayedexpansion`.

Also, as a matter of style, whereas `%%#` appears to work, only (case-sensitive) alphabetics are supported by the documentation, and there's always a possibility that Microsoft may "fix" the "problem".