# Find a file under a partially known folder path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am very new to batch files. I am trying to write a script to find this file:

```
A\Org\App\B\C\SQL Scripts\Miscellaneous\CRErrorFinder.exe
```

Where:

- `A` is any drive
  Example value `C:`
- `B` a folder name
  Example value `TEST`
- `C` a folder name, *which should start from a known number e.g. 85.*
  Example value `850-0`

What I tried:

I can loop over the drives to get my root search folder, *(something like `C:\Org\App\` or `D:\Org\App\` )*, and then use two more loops for `B` and `C`. But is there a shorter way to achieve what I am doing here?

Comment: Please post the current code you are trying to use.

Comment: This maybe will help you: (1) finding the file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876771/find-file-and-return-full-path-using-a-batch-file and (2) also browsing with FOR loop in the alphabet (browsing drive letters) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410817/for-loop-in-cmd-how-to-loop-a-to-z-for-drive-letters

Comment: Something like `DIR /B /S | FINDSTR /I /R /C:"Org.App.B.C.SQL.*Miscellaneous.CRErrorFinder.exe$"`

Comment: Can folder `B` have an arbitrary name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only safe way is to establish loops for all the parts: the drive letter, the folder `B` (anything, `*`) and the folder `C` (`85*`). The inner-most loop in the following code example iterates once only and returns the file without accessing the file system as there is no wildcard `*` or `?` (that is the nature of `for`); that is why `if exist` is used -- twice in order to match files only but not directories (note the trailing `\` for the second one, `not` to be not fulfilled for folders):

```cmd
for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    for /D %%B in ("%%A:\Org\App\*") do (
        for /D %%C in ("%%~B\85*") do (
            for %%D in ("%%~C\SQL Scripts\Miscellaneous\CRErrorFinder.exe") do (
                if exist "%%~D" if not exist "%%~D\" (
                    echo(%%~D
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The found path(s) is/are simply echoed.

---

There might be another way using `dir /S` and `findstr`, but you still have to loop through the drive letters:

```cmd
for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    dir /B /S /A:-D "%%A:\CRErrorFinder.exe" | findstr /R /I /X /C:".:\\Org\\App\\[^\\][^\\]*\\85[^\\]*\\SQL Scripts\\Miscellaneous\\CRErrorFinder\.exe"
)
```

Note that `.` means any character, `\\` is a literal `\`, `[^\\]` is a character except `\`, `*` means the previous expression zero or more times and `\.` is a literal `.`.

---

Instead of looping through the alphabet you could gather the actually available drives on your system by `wmic` and capture them by `for /F` like this:

1. All drives including network drives and such established by `subst`:

   ```cmd
   for /F "skip=1" %%A in ('wmic LogicalDisk get DeviceID') do for /F "delims=:" %%A in ("%%A") do (
       rem %%A holds the pure drive letter.
   )
   ```
2. Local drives only:

   ```cmd
   for /F "skip=1" %%A in ('wmic Volume where "DriveLetter is not Null" get DriveLetter') do for /F "delims=:" %%A in ("%%A") do (
       rem %%A holds the pure drive letter.
   )
   ```

   Or (a bit faster):

   ```cmd
   for /F "delims=:\ " %%A in ('mountvol ^| find ":\"') do (
       rem %%A holds the pure drive letter.
   )
   ```

These methods can be used for both of the aforementioned approaches instead of the `for %%A` loop.

Comment: For the drive letters, as an addition, _if you like_, `For /F "Tokens=* Delims=\ " %%A In ('MountVol^|Find ":\"') Do Echo %%A` or more simply, `For /F %%A In ('MountVol^|Find ":\"') Do Echo %%A`. _(I would guess it's quicker that loading `WMIC` too!)_

Comment: @Compo, on my system (Windows 7) `mountvol` without arguments just throws out the help page...

Comment: aschipfl, did you try the command, `MountVol|Find ":\"`? or just `MountVol`? and did you not notice any mounted drive letters in the output. _I've been using that particular `For` loop certainly since `XP`, possibly `2000` and I've never known it not to work as intended!_

Comment: @Compo, yes I did, and the result is `C:\`, `E:\`, `D:\`, which I interpreted as sample output rather than actual ones; however, these are just the local drives, of course, any network drives or such established by `subst` are not returned by `mountvol`, so it finally depends on what the OP wants. Thanks anyway!

Comment: By the way, `wmic Volume where "DriveLetter is not Null" get DriveLetter` gives the same result as `mountvol`, hence local drives only...